# Tool to convert queries with Non-ANSI syntax to ANSI syntax in SQL Sever 2008 R2

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

*As a background, our system was working from `SQL 2000` and was using the `Non-ANSI` syntax to write the queries. When we migrated to `SQL 2008 R2`, we have modified the `"= * " and " * ="` with `RIGHT` as well as `LEFT join`s. But now we are planning to migrate to `SQL 2016`. The Comma JOINs are deprecated. We can use the Comma Joins in this version also, but `Microsoft` suggests like this will impact the performance of the queries. Also we don't know how long SQL Server will extend the support on these `Non-ANSI` components.*

Now we are looking for a **tool (either Microsoft or Thirdparty)** which can scan the stored procedures and will be able to change the `Non-ANSI` syntax like `','` and to replace this with `INNER JOIN` or `JOIN`.

So far I have tried with

> Toad for Oracle
>   https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10/t/9518

and noticed that it is not giving the proper output.

Also used couple of other tools, both of them not serving the purpose.

> http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/rewrite-oracle-propriety-joins-to-ansi-sql-compliant-joins/
>
> http://info.swissql.com/products/sqlone-apijava/sqlone-apijava.html

It will be helpful if anybody who came across the similar scenario can shed some light on this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can replace the commas in the `FROM` clause with `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Shift+Q in Sql Server management studio which will generate ansi standard query. But not sure for all the queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly I don't think I would trust any tool to get this right for anything except a single join. You will need to run the old code and the new code and make sure you get the same results.

What I would suggest is that you target which queries to fix by identifying the ones that take the longest in your current environment (and maybe look at some performance tuning if they are truly long-running while you are at it) and those queries run most frequently. Since the 2016 version is going to allow you to use the deprecated syntax, by fixing the most critical ones first, you will avoid the worst of the potential performance issues. I would suggest getting the top 10 longest running queries and the top ten most frequently used ones, fixing those, then moving on to the next ten of each category.

Most critical is to train your devs not to use this syntax anymore. Also you can have them fix any query they need to touch for maintenance or bugs while they are at it and enforce that through 100% code review.

Comment: Thanks. But there are couple of ways to attain this I believe. As of now no tools available in the market which will support migrating stored procedure from one version to another. But there are tools like TOAD and SWISSQL which will help to convert the syntax to Oracle. So one way is to convert the procedures to Oracle first and then converting them back to SQL Server. I never tried this. So I do not know whether this is feasible:)